# Booting Debian after upgrade

Tags: linux, boot, debian, grub

I have a Debian server.

There was a power failure recently and now I'm getting errors during boot up. I had performed a dist-upgrade recently from Squeeze to Wheezy but I don't think my kernel got upgraded.

Here's all the information I managed to capture:

[image]

Let me know if there's anything else that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it totally looks like file system corruption caused due to sudden power failure. This usually happens when power goes out before the system has finished writing to the disk. You can try to boot to safe mode (or rescue shell or Advanced options or whatever it's called) and run file system check using `fsck`. This should fix at least a few problems so that you can boot up and take care of the rest manually. If you are not able to boot at all, you may have to use some live distro to run `fsck` on at least the root partition of affected system.

Comment: Thanks. Booted using a Debian LiveCD. Selected 686-pae as the image. Ran `fsck` which claims that the partition is 'clean'. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Dumb question: Are you sure that you checked the partition of affected system and not the live system? I did that more than once - absent minded. You may try to scan all partitions on the disk. If that doesn't help, I'm afraid, the clean install would be preferable against headache of ironing out each and every error on the current system.

Comment: I think I ran it on the right partition (at least I'd like to think). In my case, it was `/dev/sda2`. I checked the available partitions using `fdisk -l`

Comment: Backup and clean install seems to be a good option then. Halfway upgraded and corrupt systems have only given me headache in past. Even if you manage to resurrect the current system, there's no telling when some odd issue would pop up which was overlooked initially.